# How to make RESTAPI calls in android using node.js

Tags: android, json, node.js

I have created a RESTAPI in Node.js and trying it to invoke into my android application. But i am not able to make the request to the Node.js Rest API.

My code are as follows:

Node.js

```
 var restify = require('restify');
 var request = require('request');
 var http    = require('http');
 var appContext = require('./config.js');

 function labsAPI(jsonparseStr) {
    return JSON.stringify(labsapi);
 }


 function searchbase(req, res, next){


    var options = {
        host: appContext.host,
        path: appContext.path+req.params.name+appContext.queryString
    };

   cbCallback = function(response) {
    var str = '';

    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        jsonparseStr = JSON.parse(str);
        json_res = labsAPI(jsonparseStr);
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'application/json'});
        res.end(json_res);
       });
   }
    http.request(options, cbCallback).end();
 }

  var server = restify.createServer({name:'crunchbase'});
  server.get('/search/:name',searchbase);

  server.listen(appContext.port, function() {
     console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
  });
```

After running my code like : localhost:8084/search/name

I am able to return the output to the browser a valid Json.

Now i want to consume this web service into my android application , I am not able to figure out how to do it.
I tried some of the example 
 http://hmkcode.com/android-parsing-json-data/

In the above blog in MainActivity.java  i changed  my url to

```
    new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://127.0.0.1:8084/search/name");
```

but it is displaying nothing

Comment: As Kevin Busse said, you need your IP. On *nix, you get that with `ifconfig`, and Windows use `ipconfig`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is the IP address for localhost. From your browser localhost resolves to your computer, from your Android device localhost resolves to your Android device, but your node application isn't running on it.

You need to figure out what's your computer's remote address. LAN or WLAN would be enough as long as your on the same network as your Android device.

Also make sure firewall settings allow access to your computer.

Comment: I think he's running the server on his local machine but is just confused because he forgot that his local machine is not his phone.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but tried to explain it from an Android developers perspective who possibly is new to node.js or even web development

Comment: I just realized I said the same thing as you /facepalm.

Comment: Thanks guys. I figured it out on your suggestion and after giving my network address for LAN it's working fine now